# I have an exam tomorrow and can't seem to solve this Logarithmic Equations question.

Tags: logarithms

The question is "The solution of $2^{2x+3} = 2^{x+1} + 3$ can be expressed in the form $a + \log_2 (b)$ where $a,b$ are integers. Find the value of $a$ and $b$."

I tried putting $\log_2$ on both sides but I couldn't do anything after that because the argument on the right hand side is a sum. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to look for patterns, sometimes this will lead somewhere useful. For example, factor the $2^{x+1}$ out as @user715522 has done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$2\cdot2^{2\left(x+1\right)}-2^{\left(x+1\right)}-3=0$$

now use $2^{\left(x+1\right)}=t$

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks a million!

Comment: @FernAdams, for your info the final answer is $x=\log_{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-1$

Comment: If $x=a+\log_2(b)$ and $a,b$ are integers then $a=-2, b=3$.